# Google play services and relation with android version

Tags: android, google-play-services

I will be developing an app that uses Google Vision API in order to scan barcode. I am successfully able to write and test the app. However, I found out that the API has to be supported for Android's ICS i.e. version 4 and above. I am using Google Play Services 8.4 version. Will I be able to use this app? I have just created a prototype of app only.

In short is there any relationship between google play services and android version? If yes where can I find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/google-play-services-8-4-89-release/#downloads) is what I was looking for. I wanted to check if version 8.4 of google play services is available for android 2.3 or not.

Answer (score 0):

you may refer to this link in order to know more regarding google play services and android versions. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: here i am not able locate any info about versions supported. I am able to see that AVD is supported from 4.2.2 and play services from version 2.3. Nothing else.